# Sagemaker Neo compilation failed for TFLite object detection model

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to compile a TFLite object detection model for imx8qm using Sagemaker Neo. I supplied a .tflite file and specified the input config like this: `{"input":[1, 300, 300, 3]}`

But the compilation failed with the following error:
`ClientError: InputConfiguration: Framework cannot load TFLite model. Unable to infer tensor data type for all inputs/outputs: Please specify all input layers in data_shape.`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Neo requires the model file(s) zipped  as a tar file (.tar.gz) before giving it as input.

If that doesn't solve the problem, you can visualize your model using [Netron](https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/). It might help figure out any inconsistencies with the input shape.

Comment: thanks for your response.Yes I did supply it as a tar file. I tried the coco_ssd_mobilenet_v1 tflite model rather than my own model. That is the inout shape mentioned for this model. Anyway I will keep trying.